# Getting undefined method qouted_table_name on associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having problems fixing association that is working on a rails 2 application. I'm this error on my local machine:

> undefined method `quoted_table_name' for Enrollment:Module

I can't seem to figure out where the error is.

Model:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :enrollment


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrollment
end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_enrollment
  end
end
```

UPDATE: 
Fixed the problem because the name of the model is the same as the name of the rails application.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error from the log file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you run `rake db:migrate` to make sure the tables exist
2. Make the following change since the nested attributes clause is misplaced

   ```
   class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
   end

   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :enrollment

     # This line belongs here right?
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrollment 
   end
   ```

Comment: Sorry for that I have edited it again. I'm still getting the error.